# OSAKit.framework usage for executing scripts

Tags: objective-c, macos, applescript

I am on XCode 9.2, Objective-C, MacOS

i am looking for any example on using osakit.framework to execute a script file(applescript = .scpt or .applescript) or a method in that file with parameters and how to get the response.

My own implementation of applescript works but leaks too much memory so i want to try osakit.framework but its documentation is bad.

The simple implementation is like this

```
OSAScript *scriptNAME= [[OSAScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"Firefox\" to return name of window 1"];  
NSDictionary * errorDict = nil;  
NSAppleEventDescriptor * returnDescriptor = [scriptNAME executeAndReturnError: &errorDict];  
NSLog(@"%@", returnDescriptor);
```

But instead of the script as source in text form i want to load my script file.

**Edit:**

I tried it with

```
OSAScript *scriptNAME= [[OSAScript alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myScriptURL error:&error];
```

The script gets loaded but i can't call any method.
I Have two simple methods

```
on test()
display dialog "Hello World"
end

on testWithArguments:arg
display dialog (arg's item 1)
end
```

The call for the second method i tried:

```
[scriptNAME executeHandlerWithName:@"testWithArguments" arguments:@[@"Hello World"] error:&errorDict];
-- doesnt work

[scriptNAME executeHandlerWithName:@"testWithArguments:" arguments:@[@"Hello World"] error:&errorDict];
-- doesnt work
```

Comment: Did you try `initWithContentsOfURL:error:`?

Comment: Check the post, i've updated it

Comment: If your AppleScripts are embedded in your app bundle, it’s far easier just to [call their handlers directly](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/asoc.html) via [tag:applescript-objc].

Comment: that's the configuration i already have. but it leaks way too much Memory. im looking for a better way - and  i heard osascript might be the way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug found.

It was a wrong configured applescript file. Was declared as a script object from a former test. As simple applescript file it works great.